# Deploy Process Builder as Active - Test Coverage Requirement Clarification

Tags: process-builder, deployment, code-coverage, metadata-api

We're looking at activating the setting to deploy active processes and flows using the Metadata API.

When looking at the requirements, Winter 19 [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_deploy_as_active.htm) says:

> When you deploy an active process or flow in a production org,
>   Salesforce runs your org’s Apex tests and confirms that enough of your
>   processes and flows have test coverage. **Specifically, the Apex tests
>   must launch at least 75% of the total number of active processes and
>   active autolaunched flows in your org**

If I had 100 active process builders in an org:

1. Is the requirement that I have apex test methods that launch 75 of
   them (could cover only 10% of each of them individually)

*or*

2. Is the requirement that every active process builder has coverage
   for 75% of their individual elements which you can query through
   [FlowTestCoverage](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_test_coverage.htm).

Comment: i had this very question myself last week and based on a test, the 75% coverage requirement is applied per `Flow`, not across all `Flows`

Comment: I figured I was just reading it too literally, but that makes sense considering that's what `FlowTestCoverage` provides you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flow coverage requirement (default 75%) applies on a per flow basis - based on a test I ran last week

- Enabled the Deploy Flows as Activated in the target PROD org
- Deployed a new flow from sandbox + corresponding apex testclass
- Ran all tests (note that other flows and process builders did not have test classes to cover their logic paths)

As the new flow had test coverage, it deployed as activated.

Comment: Interesting, I had expected it to take into account all existing active flows as well with running all tests. Thanks for the info/confirmation

Comment: let's hope I'm right (my testing was limited)  - LMK if you see otherwise.

Comment: The description says "The required percentage is the same as the code coverage requirement for Apex code" which I would read as meaning you need to have a total coverage that is at least 75% of the elements across all the flows being deployed.

I have, at this point, assumed that this doesn't apply to screen flows. I wonder if that is a correct assumption?